# How do I create entities from an archetype that are renderable

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im playing around with the new DOTS packages.

One thing i have not managed to do is use an archetype to create an entity that is visible in the scene. This is what I have so far, I can see the entities being created in the entity debugger, but they are not rendered. Any help is appreciated. I guess i'm missing some component on the archetype.

```cs
    using Unity.Entities;
    using Unity.Mathematics;
    using Unity.Transforms;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class CreateStuff : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int CountX = 100;
        public int CountY = 100;

        void Start()
        { 
            var entityManager = World.Active.EntityManager;
            var archetype = entityManager.CreateArchetype(typeof(Translation), typeof(Scale), typeof(Rotation), typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(MeshFilter));
            for (int x = 0; x < CountX; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < CountY; y++)
                {
                    var instance = entityManager.CreateEntity(archetype);
                    var position = transform.TransformPoint(new float3(x - CountX / 2, noise.cnoise(new float2(x, y) * 0.21F) * 10, y - CountY / 2));
                    entityManager.SetComponentData(instance, new Translation() { Value = position });
                    entityManager.SetComponentData(instance, new Scale() { Value = 1 });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are still looking for an answer. This is how I managed to get it working.

```
[SerializeField] private Mesh _mesh;
[SerializeField] private Material _mat;
private void Start()
{
      EntityManager entityManager = World.DefaultGameObjectInjectionWorld.EntityManager;

      EntityArchetype entityArchetype = entityManager.CreateArchetype(
                  typeof(RenderMesh),
                  typeof(LocalToWorld),
                  typeof(RenderBounds),
    );

    // create 100 entities
    NativeArray<Entity> entityArray = new NativeArray<Entity>(100, Allocator.Temp);
    entityManager.CreateEntity(entityArchetype, entityArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < entityArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Entity entity = entityArray[i];

        entityManager.SetSharedComponentData(entity, new RenderMesh
        {
            mesh = _mesh,
            material = _mat,
        }); 
    }
    entityArray.Dispose();
}
```

I did this by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILfUuBLfzGI) tutorial on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the GameObjectConversionUtility

```
    public GameObject Prefab;

    var prefab = Unity.Entities.GameObjectConversionUtility.ConvertGameObjectHierarchy(Prefab, World.Active);
    var entityManager = World.Active.EntityManager;
    var instance = entityManager.Instantiate(prefab);
```

And if your Prefab has a renderer it will automagicly have one when it's an entity

If you haven't, do check out the ECS examples: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/EntityComponentSystemSamples

Comment: yeah i have seen those examples. I could use a prefab, but I wanted to try a programmatic approach as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with code itself.
I had same problem and First of all u have to install "Hybrid Renderer" (Windeow=> Package Manager=> Advanced => Show preview pacages => Hybrid Renderer)

My code works fine. You can instantiate objects from entities and prefabs

```
public class ECSObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ECSObjectSpawner instance;
    private World _defaultWorld;
    private EntityManager _entityManager;

    public List<FromGameObject> fromGameObjects;
    private Dictionary<string, Entity> _convertedFromGo;

    public List<FromEntity> fromEntities;
    private Dictionary<string, FromEntity> _generatedFromEntity;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = instance ?? this;
        _convertedFromGo = new Dictionary<string, Entity>();
        _generatedFromEntity = fromEntities.ToDictionary(x => x.prefabName, x=>x);
    }
    void Start()
    {
        // setup references to World and EntityManager
        _defaultWorld = World.DefaultGameObjectInjectionWorld;
        _entityManager = _defaultWorld.EntityManager;
        GameObjectConversionSettings settings = GameObjectConversionSettings.FromWorld(_defaultWorld, null);
        _convertedFromGo = fromGameObjects.ToDictionary(x => x.prefabName, x=> GameObjectConversionUtility.ConvertGameObjectHierarchy(x.gameObjectPrefab, settings));
    }

    public void Instantiate(string key, float3 position, quaternion rotation)
    {
        if (_generatedFromEntity.TryGetValue(key, out FromEntity fromEntity))
        {
            InstantiateFromEnity(position, rotation, fromEntity);
            return;
        }
        if (_convertedFromGo.TryGetValue(key, out Entity entity))
        {
            InstantiateFromGameObject(position, rotation, entity);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void InstantiateFromEnity(float3 position, quaternion rotation, FromEntity fromEntity)
    {
        EntityArchetype archetype = _entityManager.CreateArchetype(
            typeof(Translation),
             typeof(Rotation),
             typeof(RenderMesh),
             typeof(RenderBounds),
             typeof(LocalToWorld)
         );

        Entity myEntity = _entityManager.CreateEntity(archetype);

        _entityManager.AddComponentData(myEntity, new Translation
        {
            Value = position
        });
        _entityManager.AddComponentData(myEntity, new Rotation
        {
            Value = rotation
        });

        _entityManager.AddSharedComponentData(myEntity, new RenderMesh
        {
            mesh = fromEntity.unitMesh,
            material = fromEntity.unitMaterial
        });
    }

    private void InstantiateFromGameObject(float3 position, quaternion rotation, Entity entity)
    {
        Entity myEntity = _entityManager.Instantiate(entity);
        _entityManager.SetComponentData(myEntity, new Translation
        {
            Value = position
        });
        _entityManager.SetComponentData(myEntity, new Rotation
        {
            Value = rotation
        });
    }


}
[System.Serializable]
public sealed class FromGameObject
{
    public string prefabName;
    public GameObject gameObjectPrefab;
}
[System.Serializable]
public sealed class FromEntity
{
    public string prefabName;
    public Mesh unitMesh;
    public Material unitMaterial;
}
```